# Remove xml header from C# webservice

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I need to build an API using C# webservice, which needs to return values in json format.

Currently I have the following lines of code

```
namespace WebService1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { errMsg = "test" });
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this when the post method is invoked is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"errMsg":"test"}</string>
```

But this isn't a valid json how do I make the webservice return the json object only and not the xml headers?

Comment: have you considered using asp.net web api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling this webservice with header Content-Type: application/json will automatically transform the response to json and your xml will be gone.